# VBA how to copy all rows until blank row

Tags: excel, vba

This is part of a code that copies a row range from a template sheet, to paste onto the active sheet, incrementing a number as it does.

```
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long, i As Long

With pasteSheet
        '~~> Find the last cell to write to
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then
            '~~> Copy header row
            copySheet.Rows(1).Copy .Rows(1)
            LRow = 2
        Else
            LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            '~~> Find the previous number
            For i = LRow To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(i, 2).Value2 = varString Then
                    StartNumber = .Cells(i, 6).Value2 + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
copySheet.Range("2:17").Copy .Rows(LRow)
```

What I am trying to do, rather than specify the row range ("2:17"), is to copy all rows until reaching a blank row.

I think I need to insert something like `LRow = copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` after the `Else` but my vba is poor and I really don't know.

How could I incorporate this into the above code?

Comment: `copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Rows(LRow)`

Comment: [Find Last Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba)